# When k drawings are made in succession from n balls and every time ball is white then chance that next ball will be white

Tags: provability

A bag contains n balls; k drawings are made in succession, and the ball on each occasion is found to be white. Find the chance that the next drawing will give a white ball (i) if balls are replaced (ii) if balls aren't replaced

I found the question on the internet but couldn't find the solution. I have no idea whatsoever how to solve this. Please help.

Comment: But how many balls are black?

Comment: The question didn't specified, so I think that it can any number from zero to n

Comment: I would say $\frac{w-k}{n-k}$ if it is without replacement. It is comprehensible ? $w:=$number of white balls at the beginning.